# updating phone contact not working

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contactscontract, android-contentresolver, android-cursor

I'm tryingt ot extract my contacts and apply so changes on them but the problem is that my builder seems like it's working fine and not throwing any exception but there are no changes !

```
Cursor c;
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(ContactID), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE});
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,"blabla");
    ops.add(builder.build());

    ContentProviderResult[] res;
    try
    {
        res = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                        }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setListViewAdapter() ;
    c = getContentResolver().query(CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{ContactID}, null);
    try {
           c.moveToFirst();
           displayName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        } 
    finally
        {
                c.close();
        }
```

and here's my method to Update the adapter to a ListView of contacts

```
private void setListViewAdapter() {

    // Construct the data source
    arrayOfUsers = getContactsData();


    // update the adapter to convert the array to views
    adapter.clear();
    adapter.addAll(arrayOfUsers);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 


    // Attach the adapter to a ListView
    if (adapter!=null && lstContacts!=null)
     {
        try
        {
            lstContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error! "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
     else
        NoContacts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

and this is how I get contacts info from the phone contacts directory, which works fine.

```
private ArrayList<Contact> getContactsData() {
    String ID   = ""; 
    String name   = ""; 
    String number = ""; 

    ArrayList <Contact> mycontacts = null;
    try
    {
        //get our contact list via a Content Resolver which is the bridge between all android applications
        Uri mContacts_uri= ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        people = getContentResolver().query(mContacts_uri, // Contact URI
                                            null,    // Which columns to return
                                            null,       // Which rows to return
                                            null,       // Where clause parameters
                                            null        // Order by clause
                                            );
        int indexID = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
        int indexName = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int indexhasnumbers = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER);

        mycontacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        Contact _person = null;
        int cur = people.getCount();
        if(cur>0)
        {
            people.moveToFirst();
            do {
            ID   = people.getString(indexID);
            name   = people.getString(indexName);

            /********************************************/
            if (Integer.parseInt(people.getString(indexhasnumbers)) > 0) 
            {
                 Cursor pCur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                                         null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                                         new String[]{ID}, null);
                 try{

                 while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                      int phoneType = pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                      number = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                      switch (phoneType) {
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                                Log.e(name + "(mobile number)", number);
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                                Log.e(name + "(home number)", number);
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                                Log.e(name + "(work number)", number);
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
                                Log.e(name + "(other number)", number);
                                break;                                  
                            default:
                                break;
                      }
                  } 
                  pCur.close();
                }
                 catch(Exception e)
                 {
                     Log.e("exception found : "+ e.getMessage()," : phone number ");
                 }
            _person=new Contact(ID,name,number);
            mycontacts.add(_person);
            }
        } 
        while (people.moveToNext());
        }

     }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error! "+e.getMessage());
    }
     return mycontacts;     
}
```

but the display name still the same, I don't understand which part of the updating function is not working because none is throwing an exception

Comment: check contact database permission in your manifest file.

Comment: I'm already using the permission to READ and WRITE :  
 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
String select = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                    + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                    + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";

            Cursor c = cntx.getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select,
                    null, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
```

see this link once may this will help you

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html

Comment: I don't get it, now I'm more confused , I just tried the insert method now in the link you gave me and still is not updating my contacts ! btw I'm using the READ and WRITE permissions in my manifest.xml !

Comment: using my queary u didnt get all contacts

Comment: I did it's working , the problem is in the updating not getting the contacts

Comment: so means to say from my queary u also not able to get updated queary